# Custom Input style in React Native

Tags: swift, input, react-native

Please how can I achieve this with an input field in react native

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. Add a `View` with `flexDirection: 'row'` style. Then for each letter add a `TextInput`. There is a example [here](https://snack.expo.io/BJmRgree-).